# Flurry Crashing iOS When Resuming Background Thread [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000c58913

Tags: ios, multithreading, selector, flurry, flurry-analytics

There are a lot of posts on this 'type' of error

```
[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000c58913
```

but none of it has bearing on my situation unfortunately.

The reason is our app is crashing on a background thread with the flurry SDK. I can't investigate the stack trace any deeper because I just get machine code.

[image]

I've tried commenting every line of code inside my flurry.m file but not of it encapsulates the error because this is happening inside the flurrySDK.

Its always crashing on thread 22 when I resume from background on the function

+[FlurryProtocolData limitStringLength:]

If you have any advice what so ever on how I look at this further I would love to hear it!

Comment: NSNumber unrecognized selector length check your  [FlurryProtocolData limitStringLength:]

Comment: I dont have access to that, its in the SDK

Comment: so check param  you sent to [FlurryProtocolData limitStringLength:]? is It right type?

Comment: As the above image shows, I don't call it, from 17 to 12, thats all the SDK

Comment: It sounds a lot like the API key that you're sending to the SDK is an `NSNumber` instead of an `NSString`.

Comment: This surely is memory management issue, the memory previous occupied by object supporting "length" API is now occupied by some NSNumber. Try enabling "Enable Zombie Objects" under "Diagnostics" in "Run" for your scheme.

Comment: It looks like you're passing an NSNumber somewhere where you should be passing an NSString.  This may be a simple parm error, or it could be a zombie issue.  If it's not always an NSNumber then it's probably a zombie thing.

Answer (score 0):

We were passing an ID as one of the session parameters to Flurry.

However it doesn't cause a crash until its loaded from a background thread oddly enough.r

Making sure the ID was a string before passing it fixed the issue.